# Java: Multithreading inconsistency

Tags: java, multithreading

I've been learning Java for quite a few months now and have recently begun to teach myself about multi-threading, but, the output I get is inconsistent. See code below:

```
    public class App{



public static void main(String args[]){
    outterclass object = new outterclass(); 
    object.start(); 
    outterclass objecttwo = new outterclass();
    objecttwo.start(); 
}


}



class outterclass extends Thread{
    public void run(){
        System.out.println("One");
        System.out.println("Two");
        System.out.println("Three");

    }

}
```

I understand the concept of threading, it's supposed to run on a separate thread on the OS, and two objects of type thread such as object and objecttwo in my code above, will theoretically run concurrently or simultaneously, the problem is, SOMETIMES this happens. 
Sometimes my output is: One One Two Two Three Three, but other run times it's One Two Three One Two Three as if they were regular calls on the same main thread, not running simultaneously..

Why is this, is my first out of two questions.

On to my second question, I DO in fact know of the static Thread.sleep(MS); method from the Thread class, and I noticed when I put a Thread.sleep(); method in between each of the sysout calls in the run method, that both instances of my Thread-extending class indeed seem to run concurrently EVERY time. So, that being said, my second question is do I NEED to utilize the Thread.sleep(); method to achieve multi-threading, and or just to assure that two instances of a separately threaded class run concurrently?

Thanks to all in advance

Comment: you don't do anything to ensure the threads start at the same time, so since the workload is very small it's very likely for one thread to be done before the other even started.

Comment: What does the javadoc of `Thread.sleep` say? I has nothing to do with concurrency.

Comment: Thanks! Okay so but with that being said, even with this small workload it appears blatant that the Thread.sleep() method DOES in fact ensure that the two Thread instances are run at the same time, is that correct or is it just an illusion ? Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Ok now I see, the concept of concurrency is confined to the purpose of the Thread.sleep(); method, but running a separate thread is irrelevant to that, and rather just makes the code run on a separate thread from the main thread.. now I just wonder why I sometimes get a concurrent run even WITHOUT the Thread.sleep method, and sometimes not

Comment: It's an illusion. `sleep` only puts the current executing `Thread` to sleep. That's it.

Comment: Ordering of execution across threads is never guaranteed.

Comment: Puzzle completed, I totally get it now guys! Thanks a lot, I know it's annoying to assist with questions you had answered years ago but you really help and make a difference

Comment: `Thread.sleep(n)` does not _ensure_ anything.  It's just a function that you can call that does not return until at least `n` milliseconds later.  You can sometimes use `Thread.sleep()` calls to make it much more likely that things in different threads happen in the order you want them to happen, but they'll never actually be _guaranteed_ to happen in that order.  I like to say that, if things ever do happen out-of-order, the sleep() calls make it much more likely that the problem will be discovered by your customers instead of being discovered by your QA team.

Comment: Thank you! Even further clarity, haha I see what you mean.. So I'd imagine since the order of which threads execute when is never guaranteed, that you ought to use ONLY the main thread for executables that need to be seen at a specific time in run.